# How to terminate Lua script?

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

How would I terminate a Lua script? Right now I'm having problems with exit(), and I don't know why. (This is more of a Minecraft ComputerCraft question, since it uses the APIs included.) Here is my code:

```
while true do

    if turtle.detect() then

        if turtle.getItemCount(16) == 64 then

            exit() --here is where I get problems

        end

        turtle.dig() --digs block in front of it

    end

end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As prapin's answer states, in Lua the function `os.exit([code])` will terminate the execution of the host program. This, however, may not be what you're looking for, because calling `os.exit` will terminate not only your script, but also the parent Lua instances that are running.

In *Minecraft ComputerCraft*, calling `error()` will also accomplish what you're looking for, but using it for other purposes than genuinely terminating the script after an error has occurred is probably not a good practice.

Because in Lua all script files are also considered functions having their own scope, the preferred way to exit your script would be to use the `return` keyword, just like you return from functions.

Like this:

```
while true do

    if turtle.detect() then

        if turtle.getItemCount(16) == 64 then

            return -- exit from the script and return to the caller

        end

        turtle.dig() --digs block in front of it

    end

end
```

Comment: error() should work fine in this case, but I also added the solution that's of better practice.

Comment: Thanks, although this won't work from within a function call in the Lua program.  (I'm having the same problem.)

Comment: in computercraft "os.exit()" won't close the parent lua instance. in CC "os.exit()" is remapped to a function which will only "shutdown" the Computer or Turtle.

Answer (score 4):

The `break` statement will skip to the line after the `for`, `while`, or `repeat` loop it's in.

```
while true do
    if turtle.detect() then
        if turtle.getItemCount(16) == 64 then
            break
        end
        turtle.dig() -- digs block in front of it
    end
end
-- break skips to here
```

A quirk of lua: `break` has to come just before an `end`, though not necessarily the `end` of the loop you want to break out of, as you can see here.

Also, if you want to exit the loop on a condition at the start or end of the loop, as above, often you can change up the loop you're using to get a similar effect.  For instance, in this example we could put the condition in the `while` loop:

```
while turtle.getItemCount(16) < 64 do
  if turtle.detect() then
    turtle.dig()
  end
end
```

Note that I subtly changed the behaviour a bit there, as this new loop will stop right away when it hits the item count limit, without continuing until `detect()` becomes true again.

Answer (score 3):

There is no global function named `exit` in standard Lua.

However, there is an `os.exit` function. In Lua 5.1, it has one optional argument, the error code. On Lua 5.2, there is a second optional parameter, telling whether the Lua state should be closed before exiting.

But note that *Minecraft ComputerCraft* may provide a different function than the standard `os.exit` one.

Comment: The `os.exit()` function does not exit programs in ComputerCraft. You will get an error if you try to run it. Instead, use `shell.exit()`

http://computercraft.info/wiki/Shell.exit

Answer (score 3):

You can also terminate it manually by holding down <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> a few seconds in the turtle/computer's interface.

Answer (score 1):

don't use a `while true`

Do something like this:

```
running = true
while running do

    -- dig block
        turtle.dig() --digs block in front of it

    -- check your condition and set "running" to false
    if turtle.getItemCount(16) == 64 then
        running = false
    end

end
```

Also you don't have to call `turtle.detect()` before digging 'cause `turtle.dig()` wil call it again internal

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while true`. Instead of it use something like this:

```
while turtle.getItemCount(16) < 64 do
  if turtle.detect() then
    turtle.dig()
  end
end
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

shell.exit() closes a lua script in computer craft.
for further info go to http://computercraft.info/wiki/Shell.exit

Comment: It does not end the currently executing script. So this doesn't answer the question.